# How to downgrade from squeeze to lenny

Tags: debian

I am trying to downgrade from Squeeze back to Lenny with the usual method by adding to my `/etc/apt/preferences`:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=oldstable
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

and then doing `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` but for some reason it does not work (I got both stable and oldstable in `sources.list`)

Comment: “Does not work” is a useless description. You have the preferences right, but downgrades aren't officially supported, and typically need to be babysitted.

Comment: Right, I wouldn't post if it worked. Any details concerning "babysitting" downgrades? Would greatly appreciate.

Comment: Not `upgrade`, but `dist-upgrade`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last article I read suggested you need a fresh Lenny install I'm afraid.

Hopefully it's only 20 mins or so. I'd opt for that after a quick backup.

Comment: It seems it's necessary to download the full CD or DVD and you can't find the mirror easily on Debian website. However the page is still there so I give the address for those unlucky few who have to downgrade http://www.debian.org/releases/lenny/debian-installer/